# Corrupted disk in Gnome Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome, 17.04, disk

Well, I have Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 installed on my dektop pc, I have 4 drives, 2 for windows and 2 for Ubuntu,the os directories are installed on the ssd and the home drectory on the hdd

[drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDprF.jpg)

lately when I start on Ubuntu, the OS not boot and print this message on my screen:  [Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgphN.jpg)

I don´t know why, but for fix it, i have to boot on a usb with the os, open a terminal and write :

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sde1
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdd1
```

With this the problem is solved just for a while, and happens again, please help I'm tired to do this process again and again and again,give me a final solution for this problem.

PD: sorry for my english

Comment: In Windows, have you installed a driver that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu Ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: Yes , I have this driver , this is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a dual-boot configuration with Windows, some users find that their Ubuntu file system continually has errors.

In Windows, if you installed a driver that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu Ext2/3/4 partitions, you should uninstall it asap, because it's what's corrupting the Ubuntu file system.